# Spark: get timestamp for end of action/write

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time

I have a Spark pipeline which has 3 `DataFrame.write` and I want to output a timestamp for when each write has been done. I tried like this:

```
val timeFormat = new SimpleDataFormat("HH:mm:ss")
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

df.groupby(...)
  .agg(...)
  .write
  .csv(...)

println(timeFormat.format(calendar.getTime))
```

But what I see in the output is like:

```
2018-07-04 12:31:55 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 5 finished ...
12:25:56
```

What I need is the real end of the job, so `12:31:55` here. How can I get the correct time?

Why does this happen? I presume it's something to do with the driver script which just spawns the executor processes but keeps running, not actually waiting for the job to finish before executing the print statements. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take time just after the `write` function like below

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

    df.groupby(...)
      .agg(...)
      .write
      .csv(...)

    val currentTime=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss").format(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Answer (score 2):

As Manoj Kumar had correctly mentioned get the time after execution, just to add on, use a function to get the end time so that you could reuse.

```
scala> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

scala>

scala> def getEndTime[T](fn: => T): (T, String) = {
     |     val result = fn
     |     (result, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
     | }
getEndTime: [T](fn: => T)(T, String)

scala>

scala> def add(a : Int, b : Int) : Int = {
     |     a + b
     | }
add: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala>

scala> val (result, endTime) = getEndTime { add(10, 5) }
result: Int = 15
endTime: String = 2018/07/04 07:18:58

scala>

scala> val (result, endTime) = getEndTime { 10 + 5 }
result: Int = 15
endTime: String = 2018/07/04 07:19:00
```

So you could write something like:

```
val (_, endTime) = getEndTime { df.groupby(...)
                    .agg(...)
                    .write
                    .csv(...)}
```